# Case statement in SQLite giving wrong results

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT Protocol, case (Protocol) 
When TYPE = 1 then 'Peer' 
When TYPE = 2 then 'TCMP' 
When TYPE = 3 then 'ICMP' 
When TYPE = 4 then 'Jitter'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END as Name

From 
(
select 
Protocol from ProtocolDetails group by Protocol 
) 
as T
```

When I print the result on the table in SQLite , the output is as below

```
Protocol     Name

1            Peer
3            Unknown
4            Unknown
```

My Question is why Unknown is printed for 3 and 4 , Whats wrong with my case statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the [two types of `case`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).  Try:

```
SELECT Protocol,
       (case When TYPE = 1 then 'Peer' 
             When TYPE = 2 then 'TCMP' 
             When TYPE = 3 then 'ICMP' 
             When TYPE = 4 then 'Jitter'
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as Name
From (select Protocol
      from ProtocolDetails
      group by Protocol 
     ) T;
```

Your boolean expressions are being evaluated as numbers.